# How get values from Combobox to write into textbox

Tags: tkinter, combobox

Using "Add" button, I want  takes values from combobox into writen into entry. I also keep track of the existing values from on each click rather than allowing the user to select multiple names.
For example:

When user select g from combobox and click add button, in textbox wroten "Selected letter: g"

After user select Q and click add button, in textbox wroten "Selected letter g,Q"

After user select p and click add button, in textbox wroten "Selected letter g,Q,p"

I think I confused on defining function "Add" button.  Thanks.

```
    import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

form=tk.Tk()
form.title("Pi Theorem")
form.geometry("300x300")

x=tk.StringVar()

def Add():
    textbox.insert(x)

#buton
buton=tk.Button(form,text='EKLE',fg='black',command=Add)

buton.place(x=200,y=50,height=20)

#entry - textbox
textbox=tk.Entry(fg='black',bg='white')
textbox.pack(ipady=10)
textbox.place(width=150,height=20,x=20,y=100)

#combobox 
degiskenler=['g','Q','p','H','M']
combobox=Combobox(form, values=degiskenler,textvariable=x,height=3)
combobox.pack()
combobox.place(width=150,height=20,x=20,y=50)

form.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of the combobox in tkinter just use this command:

```
combobox.get()
```

Here is the final code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox

form=tk.Tk()
form.title("Pi Theorem")
form.geometry("300x300")


def Add():
    textbox.insert(END, combobox.get())

#buton
buton=tk.Button(form,text='EKLE',fg='black',command=Add)

buton.place(x=200,y=50,height=20)

#entry - textbox
textbox=tk.Entry(fg='black',bg='white')
textbox.pack(ipady=10)
textbox.place(width=150,height=20,x=20,y=100)

#combobox 
degiskenler=['g','Q','p','H','M']
combobox=Combobox(form, values=degiskenler,height=3)
combobox.pack()
combobox.place(width=150,height=20,x=20,y=50)

form.mainloop()
```

There is no text variable in this. Simply take the value and put it in the end of the entrybox.

Thank You!

Comment: Thank you! These codes works prefect. How I add sentence "Selected letter" and using "," between each letter. like that:  "Selected letter g,Q,p".                                                                                    
                                                      I also make limitation each character can be selected once from combobox. I dont want selected double or more same letter.  Thanks again.

Comment: Hi! Great to know the code worked. Try posting another question, as the one you asked in the comments isn't very much related. Please accept answers if they work, and upvote them if you can. This helps programmers to gain reputation and help more people. Thank You!